# How to handle special characters in .htaccess rules?

Tags: apache, url, .htaccess, url-rewriting

In my .htaccess file I have defined following rule,

```
RewriteRule t/([^.]+)/$ /videos/tag.php?tag=$1 [QSA]
```

The above rule works fine if I am browsing `http://example.com/videos/t/world+news/` or `http://example.com/videos/t/events/`

but when I am browsing `http://example.com/videos/t/business+%26+world/` (here original tag is: business & world) then in my query string `tag` variable I am getting only business. '& world' is not coming when I am fetching variable data through `$_GET['tag']`

Can anyone please tell where is the problem in the above rule??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [B flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to escape the backreference:

```
RewriteRule ^t/([^.]+)/$ /videos/tag.php?tag=$1 [B,QSA]
```

---

**Edit**   How about this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)/$ $1\%26$2 [N,NE]
RewriteRule ^t/([^.]+)/$ /videos/tag.php?tag=$1 [QSA]
```

The first rule is to replace the `&` with `%26`.

Comment: Its not working. When I am adding [B,QSA] then it gives me "500 Internal Server Error" without that B only [QSA] is working fine. ??

Comment: I think that flag was introduced with Apache 2.

Comment: Ok,but I am running my website with this configuration `Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)` and other thing is your new code is not working? don't know hwy but its displaying only a blank page after adding that %26 rule.

Comment: One more thing your new rule will only replace the `&` or it will work same like `B` flag what you suggested before.

Comment: The first rule should be applied as long as there are `&` in the URL path. So every `&` would be replaced by `%26`.

Comment: The `B` flag was introduced in 2.4.26 (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html).

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have a solution for you:

```
RewriteRule ^t/([^/.]+)/$ /videos/tag.php?tag=$1 [QSA,L]
```