# Htaccess RewriteRule to accept special characters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, alphabetical

My htaccess rewrite must handle these scenarios:

- http://example.com/words/pantalón
- http://example.com/words/pantal%C3%B3n
- http://example.com/words/señor+señora

My current .htaccess configuration is:

```
RewriteRule ^dictionary/([\w\+]{2,50})$ /words.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It is not recognizing the special chars, e.g.: ñ, ó.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Final solution**

```
RewriteRule ^dictionary/([^/.]+)$ /words.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `%` to the character class in your expression:

```
RewriteRule ^dictionary/([\w+%]{2,50})$ /words.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Or you could even use `[^/]{2,50}`.

Special (something like `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`) characters are encoded by the client upon request. Note that `åäö` would  become 9 characters, and even a single `å` would pass trough this expression. If you want to allow 50 special chars, use `{2,150}` and check both side of the range in your PHP code after decoding the string (which I guess is done for you automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Its better to convert the string into default url encode mechanism.
AFAIK the request to url#1 cannot be made without encoding the url.
Also the decoding would be done on the server side so you need not worry about that.
If you are using some framework or server side script I would suggest to pass the  `pantalón` via `POST` rather than get.

You can use jquery post
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

If you still want to go through GET :

[How to handle special characters in .htaccess rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124618/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-htaccess-rules)

Also be aware that the URLs will get encoded.

Comment: it must be done through GET because it must be a reachable url. So, what would be the best for the htaccess to accept the % and + characters as well?