# rewriterule to prevent 500 internal error with accented Characters in url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I got an unsolved problem maybe a basic one but i dont really find any answer.
My problem is with all accent characters in the url,

I got an 500 error(Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact the server administrator. (12217)).

for instant when I search "blé", in my url i got:
/content/search?SearchText=blé
and the result is 500 error, 
In my blog keywords: 
/content/keyword/blé  :  (result is 500 error).

I have created a directory out of my website folder and i have created an alias from my website to this directory.  www.mysite.com/directory 
If i put a file with an accented name the result is the same!

Can I use a rewriterule to change all accented words to non-accented or can i make my url accept these accents?

I really need help and would appreciate if anyone can just help me.

Comment: Look at Wordpress as an example. When a post is created that has accented (UTF-8) characters, it converts them BEFORE making it public which negates the fact that you now need some sort of workaround. The 500 error is also not indicative of the actual problem. Turn off friendly HTTP error messages if you're using IE to see the actual error, or check the error-log as to what is wrong

Comment: Please see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321602/htaccess-rewriterule-to-accept-special-characters

Answer (score 0):

This looks like issue on TMG/ISA firewall. On publishing rule you have to enable high bit character (right click on publishing rule, configure HTTP, general tab).