# How to pass encoded characters like %2f and %2b in a url?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am passing encrypted value through the URL using .htaccess file as shown below :
URL :

```
http://www.website.com/folder1/f1/tdT9Eu%2b8kmAe1U%2ft12RS
```

htaccess file :

```
RewriteRule ^f1/(.+)$  index.php?id=$1 [NE]
```

The issue is the server respond by The requested URL was not found on this server. but when I replace `%2f` by `/` and `%2b` b `s+`  it works perfectly  and I can see the content of the page.

it works also perfectly when I use the url without any rewriting as shown below :

```
http://www.website.com/folder1/index.php?id=tdT9Eu%2b8kmAe1U%2ft12RS
```

Could you please help with that and how can I modify my htaccess to make this work ? because I need to get the content using url rewriting as shown above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [%2F in URL breaks and does not reference to the .php file required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206835/2f-in-url-breaks-and-does-not-reference-to-the-php-file-required)

Answer (score 1):

It is due to presence of `%2f` in URI that is usually not allowed by Apache web server by default. It is allowed in query string that's why `?id=...` is working fine.

You will need to [turn on AllowEncodedSlashes directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) in Apache config for this.

Use:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

to allow encoded slash in URIs and restart your Apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the answer you're looking for here: [Htaccess RewriteRule to accept special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321602/htaccess-rewriterule-to-accept-special-characters)

Basically, change it to `RewriteRule ^f1/(^/.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [NE]`

Comment: Thank you Christopher , I'll try your solution . I let you know

Comment: Hi Christopher, Unfortunately it did not work . do you have any other idea ? thank you