# Concatenate url in smarty for a given link with string

Tags: php, html, css, smarty, shopware

When I concatenate url in smarty for a given link with string for example `' /code/1113321 '`, the href of the link is `' basic_url/code/1113321 '`, but when the link is clicked it leads to `' basic_url%2Fcode%2F1113321 '`. How to replace the `%` signs with `/`?

Comment: possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949177/url-issue-passing-encoded-characters-like-2f-and-2b

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can help such construction:

```
//index - controller name
<a href="{url controller=index code=1113321}">link</a>
```